# Suggestions on class structure

Tags: class, treeview

I am looking for suggestions on a class structure.

I am populating a TreeView with a 3 deep node structure.

```
Parent 1
   Child 1
      Sub-Child 1
      Sub-Child 2
      Sub-Child 3
   Child 2
      Sub-Child 1
      Sub-Child 2
Parent 2
   Child 1
      Sub-Child 1
   Child 2
      Sub-Child 1
      Sub-Child 2
```

Currently have I have three classes Parent, Child, Sub-Child.  Each have a list(of < lower_level_class >).  Then I was going to loop through each list to populate the treeview.

Looking for a more effective method.

Thanks
jlimited

Comment: Do parents, children and sub-children have any other data in them? Also, what is the language you are working in?

Comment: Working with VB.NET or C#.NET.  Yes Parent has a property for Name, ID , and list of Children.  Child has property for Name, ID, list of sub children.  Sub-Children has 3 property for Name, ID, and Enabled.